# Embed an image for discord using embeds

Tags: python, image, hyperlink, discord, embed

I'm trying to make an embed image command, something like `$embed (image link)`

This is my code:

```
async def image(ctx, link):
  await ctx.message.delete()
  embd = discord.Embed("")
  embed.set_image(url=link)
  await ctx.channel.send(embed=embd)
```

But it doesn't work, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You spelled your variables incorrectly. Try this out:

```py
async def image(ctx, link):
  await ctx.message.delete()
  embed = discord.Embed("")
  embed.set_image(url=link)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```